# change the value of a json encode variable

Tags: jquery

I set a jquery varibale with a php array:

```
<?
$lastMessageIDs = array(88,99);
?>

var lastMessageIDs = '<? echo json_encode($lastMessageIDs); ?>';
console.log(lastMessageIDs)
```

The result of console.log:

```
[88,99]
```

How can I change (for example) the value 99 to 77?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved as in the following:

```
lastMessageIDs = JSON.parse(lastMessageIDs); // parse it to json first
lastMessageIDs[1] = 77;
console.log(lastMessageIDs); // the result is: [88, 77]
```

**note that:** the array starts with 0 so if you want to change the second item you will type 1, more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: no, that is not correct. `console.log(lastMessageIDs[1])` => output: 8
`var lastMessageIDs` is not an array. it is an json

Comment: it's because it's string you have to parse it to json first, let me just edit the answer